# JSF Extended Datatable Sorting and Filtering

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have a extended datatable, RICHFACES 3.3.3 with sorting and filtering enabled. The table is rendered dynamically. Based on the requirement, I need to disable certain rows(which contain editable fields) when the table is displayed.

I have that logic written in a Javascript function `rowBlur()`, and call it whenever the page is displayed. Hence, when the table is loaded the required rows are disabled as expected. The problem is whenever I filter/sort the table, the disabled rows get enabled again.

Is there any way I can call the javascript function whenever filter or sort happens?

Here is the code:

```
HtmlExtendedDataTable dynamicDataTable = new HtmlExtendedDataTable();
dynamicDataTable.setOnkeydown("filterAllOnEnter(event)");

function filterAllOnEnter(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        jQuery(".rich-filter-input").blur();
        rowblur();
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

// js code////////////
<script>
function show(){
    val = '${myController.mergeWorkMap}';
}
</script>
<script>
function rowblur(){
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    var firstCol = "myForm:dynamicTable:"+i+":col0" ;
    var secondCol = "myForm:dynamicTable:"+i+":col1" ;
    var merge =document.getElementById(firstCol).textContent;
    var work =document.getElementById(secondCol).textContent;
    var obj = JSON.parse(val).mergeWorkMap;
    if(!(work == obj[merge])){
        var col3 = "myForm:dynamicTable:" + i + ":col3";
        var col4 = "myForm:dynamicTable:" + i + ":col4";
        var col5 = "myForm:dynamicTable:" + i + ":col5";
        var col6 = "myForm:dynamicTable:" + i + ":col6";
        document.getElementById(col3).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(col4).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(col5).disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById(col6).disabled = true;
    }

}
}
</script>
```

The `rowblur()` won't work properly on filtering, and on sorting the columns it won't work at all.

Comment: What does rowblur() do. post the code. And post teh code of your tabel as well.

Comment: I am not sure but try using onclick() at sorting/filtering and call that filterAllonEnter() function.

Comment: `function show(){
 val = '${myController.mergeWorkMap}';
}
<script>
show('${cotdReportController.mergeWorkMap}');
</script>
<script>
rowblur();
</script>`

Comment: `function rowblur(){
 for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
 var mrge  =document.getElementById("myForm:dynamicTable:"+i+":col0").textContent;
 var wrk =document.getElementById("myForm:dynamicTable:"+i+":col1").textContent;
 var obj = JSON.parse(jsonval1).mergeWorkMap;
 if(!(work == obj[merge])){
 var col4 = "myForm:dynamicTable:" + i + ":col4";
 var col5 = "myForm:dynamicTable:" + i + ":col5";
 var col6 = "myForm:dynamicTable:" + i + ":col6";
 document.getElementById(col4).disabled = true;
 document.getElementById(col5).disabled = true;
 document.getElementById(col6).disabled = true;
}
}
}
`

Comment: @roel, I have been told that I should use jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(), but that seems to work with JSF2, but I have used JSF1.2. Please help

Comment: edit your question with your code, here in the comments it is unreadable.

Comment: in the for loop of the rowBlur(), I have iterated till 7, but actually i'll be iterating it for the size of the list.

Comment: @roel, rowblur will get called on keydown event for filtering, although it's not working properly.. how to call it when I sort the table. Is it possible that I call the rowBlur function every time the table is sorted/filtered just before the table is rendered???

Comment: Like I asked before. Post the code of your table. Your requesting help, then invest in your question and give source of the things you use. Don't make it to difficult for people here who might try to answer your question.

Comment: Can't you disable the fields server side? Or call your rowblur with a onclick event on your headers (sorting is done when clicking the header, right?)?